# Are variables to the left of | in set-builder notation free? How is that variable quantified in the equivalent definition?

Tags: logic, notation, arithmetic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have a problem in understanding quantification for set-builder notation (comprehensions) and equational definitions. For example, $odd$ natural numbers can expressed as:

$\{ x \in \Bbb N \mid \exists k \in \Bbb N, x = 2k+1 \}$ (1) set builder,correction suggested by John Hughes

$\exists k \in \mathbb{N} : x = 2k + 1 $ ([2](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Odd_Integer)) definition

as a comprehension and a definition.

With respect to comprehensions, in the absence of an explicit quantifier, are the variables before $|$ considered free in comprehensions?

With respect to equational definition, I am unsure of $Odd$ as a predicate, where $x$ is on the left of the equation.

$\text {Odd}(x) \text {  iff  } \exists k \in \mathbb N \ (x=2k+1)$

Are the variables in arguments of such predicates, and even functions, considered free?

Comment: Item "1" is nonsense. Somewhat better (and fairly conventional) would be $\{2k+1 \mid k \in \Bbb N\}$. Slightly better than that would be $\{ x \in \Bbb N \mid \exists k \in \Bbb N, x = 2k+1 \}$, for then it's clear that the set is being formed via comprehension.

Comment: The first version (duly corrected) is the _set_ of all odd numbers. The second version is a _definition_ of what it means to say that $x$ is odd. These are different things.

Comment: The answer from @Mauro ALLEGRANZA has helped clear my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is the definition of the *predicate* $\text {Odd}(x)$ :

> $\text {Odd}(x) \text {  iff  } \exists k \in \mathbb N \ (x=2k+1)$.

In (2) the variable $k$ is bound, while the variable $x$ is *free*.

This corresponds to the fact that we are defining a *unary* predicate (a "property") that will hold of all and only those numbers $n$ that satisfy the corresponding formula.

---

(1), slightly corrected : $\{ x \mid \exists k ∈ \mathbb N \ (x=2k+1) \}$, is the definition of the *set* $\text {Odd}$ of *odd* numbers.

In (1) we are using the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), whose syntax is $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$, where $\varphi(x)$ is a formula with variable $x$ occurring free.

In our case the formula is again $\exists k ∈ \mathbb N \ (x=2k+1)$, where $k$ is bound.

The set-builder notation acst itself as a quantifier, binding the variable $x$. This corresponds to the fact that the notation does not define a property, but use a (formula expressing a) property to define a *set* : the set of all and only those $x$ that satisfy the formula.

---

There is a simple link between the two expressions :

> $x \in \text {Odd} \text {   iff   }  \text {Odd}(x)$.

Comment: As written, item $1$ is nonsensical. You might want to rewrite that.

Comment: @YiFan I have added the suggested corrections.

Comment: I have updated the set builder notation and predicate definition so that they both contain two variables.